# Update all documents in a Firestore collection except for a pre-defined number which is based off date created

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am working on a project that when a user cancels their plan, all their documents should be updated to deactivated except for a pre-defined number of documents that are allowed to stay active. The pre-defined number amount determines the projects allowed to stay active along with the date they were created.

For example, if customer A has 1,000 documents and cancels their plan, all their documents except for the first 100 created should be updated to be deactivated.

My first attempt was to get all document ids with `.listDocuments()` but I noticed the created date is not part of Firestore's `DocumentReference`. Therefore I can't exclude the pre-defined number of documents allowed to stay active.

I could use `.get()` and use the created value, but I'm afraid that getting all the documents at once (which could be a million) would cause my cloud function to run out of memory, even if I have it set to the maximum allowed configuration.

Another option that I thought of, I could use `.listDocuments()` and write each document id to a temp collection in Firestore, which could kick off a cloud function for each document. This function would only have to work with one document, so it wouldn't have to worry about running out of resources. I am unsure how to determine if the document I'm working on should be marked as deactivated or is allowed to stay active.

I am not that worried about the reads to write as this workflow should not happen very often. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One possible approach would be to mark the documents to be excluded.

I don't know what is your exact algorithm, but if you want to mark the first 100 documents that were created in a collection you can use a Cloud Function that runs for each new document and checks if there are already 100 docs in the collection.

If not, you update a field in this new document with its rank (using a Transaction to get the highest existing rank and increment it). If there are already 100 documents previously created in the collection, you just update the field to `0`, for example, in such a way that later on you can query with `where("rank", "==", 0)`.

Then, when you want to delete all the docs but the 100 first ones, just use `where("rank", "==", 0)` query.

So, concretely:

The first doc is created: you set the `rank` field to 1.

The Nth doc (N != 1) is created: you fetch all the docs with a query ordered by `rank` and limited to 1 doc (`collecRef.orderBy("rank", "desc").limit(1)`) in a Transaction. Since you are in a Cloud Function, you can use a Query in the Transaction (which you cannot with the Client SDKs). Then, still in the Transaction:

- If the value of `rank` for the single doc returned by the Query is < 100 you set the `rank` value of the newly created do to [single doc value + 1]
- If the value of rank for the single doc returned by the Query =  100 you set the `rank` value to `0`

If I didn't make any mistake (I didn't test it! :-)) you end with 100 docs with a value of `rank` between 1 and 100 (the 100 first created docs) and the rest of the docs with a value of `rank` equal to `0`.

Then, as said above you can use the `where("rank", "==", 0)` query to select all the docs to be deleted.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the user can always delete documents, so the 100 allowed documents would not necessarily be the first 100 created. Just the first 100 created documents that are still in the Firestore collection.  I could achieve this by changing rank once one document is deleted or created. I don't know if this would be the best solution considering that.